# how to use tf.gradients and gradients_apply

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

I computed gradients using (tf.vars is list of tensors that are trainable)

```
x = tf.gradients(y,tf.vars)
```

now suppose that I want to apply this gradients using optimizer.apply_gradients, then I need to give a list containing tuples of the form of (gradient,variable). 
How do I generate such a list?

```
optimizer.apply_gradients(??)
```

What goes in the space ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list to pass to optimizer.apply_gradients should be a list of pairs `(g, v)` where `v` is a Variable of the graph and `g` the gradient w.r.t. you want to update `v`.

So something like this should work:

```
[(g, v) for g, v in zip(x, tf.vars)]
```

Comment: the problem is that how do I confirm whether the ordering of the variables in x is the same as that in tf.vars?

Comment: it is ensured by tf.gradients: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/gradients

Comment: the documentation does not say that the odering of variables remains unchanged.

Comment: "A list of sum(dy/dx) for each x in xs"

Comment: yeah but the ordering of elements might be not the same as xs?

Comment: it is the same order. You can check this by writing something like `a=tf.Variable(3); b=tf.Variable(4); s = 2 * a + 4 * b; g_ab = tf.gradients(s, [a, b]); g_ba = tf.gradients(s, [b, a])` and running the tensors `g_ab` and `g_ba`